# Vue model: binding nested data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

How can I bind the following nested data with `v-model`?

```
<div v-for="(frame, i) in frames" :key="frame.id" class='well'>
  <div v-for="(value, key) in frame" :key="key">
    {{ key }}:
    <input type="text" :v-model="frame[i].key" :id="key.id">
  </div>
</div>
```

With this kinda data stored in `this.frames`:

```
[{"x": 0, "y" : 0, "width": 10, "height": 10, "direction": "down", "div": "header", "page_number": 1}]
```

Obviously there can be many objects in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone playing along at home:

```
<input type="text" v-model="frames[i][key]" :id="key.id" class="form-control">
```

Note the no colon here (`:v-model="frame[i].key"`) *despite* dynamic key names, and note the comment from @Stephen Thomas explaining how the inference that `colon = dynamic` is wrong.

Comment: The colon doesn't (explicitly) designate attributes as "dynamic." Rather, it's just a convenient shortcut for `v-bind:` Once you understand that, it's easier to see that `v-bind:v-model` wouldn't make any sense while, for example, `v-bind:id` does.